# MVC4 routing issue. Not able to customize URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Below is my RouteConfig.cs.

I want to create a URL like this

```
http://localhost:22723/Home*Index
```

So I have the Routeconfig.cs  as per below . I removed all the default setting.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default3",
    url: "{controller}*{action}*{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When i am typing URL like below it does not work.

```
http://localhost:22723/Home*Index
```

Please suggest why this the above URL is not working and how to get it work,

Is this kind of URL is possible in MVC4.

Comment: `*` is considered as security issue in url, so you can't use it , may be there must be some other alternative instead of `*` . Hpe [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) helps

Comment: I tried using http://localhost:22723/Home-Index , it did not work. Routes.MapRoute( name: "Default3", url: "{controller}-{action}-{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

Comment: why do you want some other characters instead of `/` ?  @Hemanta

Answer (score 0):

As J Santosh pointed out, using `*` is possible in a URL but you will have to disable the request validation in order to make it work (not recommended).

If you want to use another character (besides `/`) you need to build your route scheme differently because the `Route` class does not understand how to make any other literal character besides `/` optional. Here is an example using a `-` literal character, but any other character that is valid in a URL will work the same way.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // This must be first to prevent the home page from
        // being generated as /Home-Index
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ThreePlaceholders",
            url: "{controller}-{action}-{id}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "TwoPlaceholders",
            url: "{controller}-{action}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "OnePlaceholder",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index" }
        );
    }
}
```

The trick is you need to make a complete set of URL patterns and make each of the placeholders ***required*** in order to ensure each route only matches in one specific case. You can make a placeholder required by not providing a default value.

The routing framework matches the URL patterns from the first registered route to the last and the first match always wins. So in this case you need multiple patterns to handle the optional literal characters in the URL.